# service metasploit start failed to start metasploit service

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux

I am trying to setup Metasploit for penetration testing.

However, I cannot get the database to connect. Also whenever I attempt to start the service using `service metasploit start` I get the following error:

```
failed to start metasploit.service 
unit metasploit.service failed to load 
no such file or directory
```

I find this odd because I am able to run the program using:

```
msfconsole
```

I haven't been able to find any solutions online, can anyone here help me out?

Comment: have you tried the metasploit forums on Rapid7?

Comment: When I Google the error, I get directed here: https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-20-released/

Comment: did you use the new Kali method for starting metasploit?

Comment: I'm closing this because it belongs on a Kali or metasploit forum. An answer was found in 30 seconds of Googling the error, resulting in a Kali forum post.

Answer (score 8):

```
#/etc/init.d/postgresql
service --status-all
service postgresql start
service postgresql status
```

```
#/usr/bin/msfconsole
msfdb init
msfconsole
msf > db_status
```